# Active Directory Group Policy: Script Errors

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, vmware-fusion

Anyone having issues with AD group policy script errors when enabling VMware Fusion's "Sharing" feature? I've run into this problem in version 2.0 and 3.0. I have a logon script applied on an AD OU. It works fine on all Windows client workstations and in VMware Fusion only when the "Sharing" feature is NOT enabled. Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the logon script manually once you log in? any error output ? What is failing about the script?

My completely off the wall guess is that the sharing feature is mapping drives that your script then tries to map, causing it to fail.